# Docker-compose - npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script

Tags: docker, nginx, npm, docker-compose

I have an app built with docker-compose, which was working perfectly until I did a new:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d --build`.

Even though I haven't *touched* my 'client' service config, it now breaks with the following log:

```
The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-17T21_19_15_181Z-debug.log

> client@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
> react-scripts start
```

Serivce now `nginx` fails to connect upstream to 'client'.

```
...

client:
    build:
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    env_file:
      - .env-dev
    depends_on:
      - web
```

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Docker networks are so sensitive.

What fixed it for me, after rebuilt:

```
$ docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc) --force
```

then:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml down
```

and finally:

```
$docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d
```